# Assign local variable within scriptblock

Tags: powershell

I am trying to assign a local variable from within a scriptblock with no luck. The goal is log a status of each machine for the action taken with the data prior and the data after the change. I am not sure how to assign a local variable from within a script block. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$csvContents = @() # Create the empty array that will eventually be the CSV file
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter '(OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*") -and (Name -like "AD*")' | Sort-Object Name
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $row = New-Object PSObject # Create an object to append to the array
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value NotSet
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PingStatus" -Value NotSet
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DNSChangeStatus" -Value NotSet
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "BeforeChange" -Value NotSet
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AfterChange" -Value NotSet
    #Write-Host "$($Computer.Name): " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $row.ComputerName = $Computer.Name
    $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $Computer.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet
    if ($rtn -match 'True') {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $Computer.DnsHostname
        $row.PingStatus = 'Pingable'
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock {
            $NewDnsServerSearchOrder = "10.93.108.225","10.93.108.134"
            $Adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne 'True' -and $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -eq "10.93.108.226"}
            if ($Adapters -ne $null) {
                # Show DNS servers before update
                Write-Host "Before: " -ForegroundColor Green
                $row.DNSChangeStatus = 'Change Needed'
                $Adapters | ForEach-Object {
                    $_.DNSServerSearchOrder
                    $row.BeforeChange = $_.DNSServerSearchOrder
                }
                # Update DNS servers
                $Adapters | ForEach-Object {$_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($NewDnsServerSearchOrder)} | Out-Null
                # Show DNS servers after update
                $Adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne 'True' -and $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $null}
                Write-Host "After: " -ForegroundColor Green
                $Adapters | ForEach-Object {
                    $_.DNSServerSearchOrder
                    $row.AfterChange = $_.DNSServerSearchOrder
                }
            } else {
                Write-Host "No DNS change needed " -ForegroundColor Yellow
                $row.DNSChangeStatus = 'No DNS Change Needed'
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $Computer.DnsGostname
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Host not pingable"
        $row.PingStatus = 'Not Pingable'
    }
    $csvContents += $row # append the new data to the array
    $row = $null
}
$csvContents | Export-Csv -Path C:\DNSChanges.csv
```

Comment: You don't need to create an empty array first. Just pipe your scriptblock to `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you want to do so I'll guess it's "pass a variable to scriptblock being invoked on a remote machine". If this is the case, you can either add parameters to the scriptblock or use the `$using:` qualifier as in:

```
$using:row.DNSChangeStatus = 'Change Needed'
```

Note that you can't "return" anything that way so you'd have to actually return the modified object from `Invoke-Command`.

```
$row = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock {
```

and add

```
$row
```

as the last line of the scriptblock.